# Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Constants' while creating a new Team Project in TFS

Tags: team-project

TFS 2013 update 5:

Scenario: creating a new Team Project using visual studio:

Exception Message: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Constants' with unique index 'IX_Constants__String_RemovedDate'. The duplicate key value is (1, 172c9245-8dad-48a7-b583-891fb1d51a19\Areas Admins, Jan  1 9999 12:00AM).

Investigation results: "172c9245-8dad-48a7-b583-891fb1d51a19" is a project ID already created 6 months ago and it is not last one to be created.

Things I tried:

-Delete client cache

-Detete server cache

-iisreset

-server restart

Comment: What version of Visual Studio you use? Did you create a team project in a collection upgraded from old version TFS? Could you create a team project in other collections?

Comment: Are other users able to create a team project? If the old team project is unnecessary , delete the old team project and created again.

Comment: @Tingting0929-MSFT
1- I am using Visual Studio 2013 professional edition
2- Yes my TFS has been upgraded from an older version
3- other users aren't able to create as well
4- the old team project is fully functional and can't deleted, too much history

Comment: Please try to reconfigure your TFS application tire. [Remove it](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AopgZUVNxLwJgUNXsV2VuzyWFIE7) and configure it again(choosing application tire only). Make sure you backup your TFS dbs.

Comment: Same question for your reference: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/395036d1-c839-4931-963a-f45e5c41cf89/unable-to-create-team-projects-cannot-insert-duplicate-key-row-in-object-dboconstants-with?forum=tfsgeneral